# C: How to Shield Commas in Macro Arguments?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a general method to shield comments in macro arguments in C? I know that parentheses can be used for this purpose, but that will not work in cases where added parentheses result in syntax errors in the macro output. I've heard that ({ }) works to shield commas in GCC, but I need this code to also work in VC++ (one of the recent versions which does conform to the C standard with regard to commas in macros). I also cannot use variadic macros in my case.

The specific case I'm trying to do is this (lengthof is a macro defined elsewhere). I'm trying to write a single macro for the entire thing because this will be used many times, and having a multi-macro solution would add a large amount of additional testing code.

```
#define TEST_UNFUNC(func, res_type, res_set, op_type, op_set) \
{ \
    static const res_type res[] = res_set; \
    static const op_type op[] = op_set; \
    int i; \
    for (i = 0; i < MIN(lengthof(res), lengthof(op)); i++) \
        assert(func(op[i]) == res[i]); \
}
```

If possible I would like a general answer and not merely a workaround specific to this particular macro.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where these commas are going to come from and what they need to be "shielded" from? Do you want to be able to do something like `MYMACRO(1, 2, 3)` and somehow signal that `1, 2` is one argument?

Comment: Parentheses will shield the commas, but you'll have a hard time of removing them in them from the macro output without variadic macros. (Well, IDK how to do it without them, perhaps you'll come up with something.)

Comment: @PSkocik who doesn't have variadic macros these days?

Comment: @o11c The OP, it would appear :(

Comment: ...and there is always the funky `do{...}while(0)`

Comment: @PSkocik I'm pretty sure the OP only means "I need more stuff in *this* macro so variadic macros aren't *applicable*". My method lets multiple arguments contain commas.

Comment: ...and the real answer is possibly:use a static function, and allow it to be inlined.

Comment: That macro is big enough that ideally it should be converted to a function.  However, since you're passing type names as arguments to the macro, that's not feasible.  You should really provide a motivating example use of the macro — an example of the call that needs commas that aren't manageable, along with an explanation of why the commas are needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parentheses to shield the comma, and then pass them through a special `unparen` macro, defined in the example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define really_unparen(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define invoke(expr) expr
#define unparen(args) invoke(really_unparen args)


#define fancy_macro(a) printf("%s %s\n", unparen(a))

int main()
{
    fancy_macro(("Hello", "World"));
}
```

The trick here is that the `invoke` macro forces an extra expansion, allowing `really_unparen` to be called even though it's not followed by parentheses in the source.

Edit: per comment below, this appears to not be necessary in this case. Though I'm sure I've hit a case where I needed it *sometime* ... and it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I believe `#define fancy_macro(a) printf("%s %s\n", really_unparen a)` should suffice. (The `invoke` and `unparen` macros shouldn't be necessary)

Comment: ... huh. Then what did I have 20 minutes ago that *didn't* work?

Comment: Just something to note, this still doesn't conform to the C standard because of the use of a variadic macro.

Comment: examples for where you may need this are passing initializer lists or doing something more finicky with the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) (can't remember how but I did once run into a problem with that)

Comment: ah yes, using the comma operator returns an r-value, so if you want to assign to it, you may want to remove the parenthesis, add the `= something` and put them back on.
so for instance `(var1, var2)` would become `(var1, var2 = something)`, since `(var1, var2) = something` doesn't work in C

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to avoid putting a comma in the first place:

```c
#define COMMA ,

#define FUNCTION_SIG(returnType, name, args) returnType name(args)

FUNCTION_SIG(int, add, int a COMMA int b);
```

Expanded code

```c
int add(int a, int b);
```