# Fortran and cpp option : How to protect a comma?

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

An option is defined (value = 1 or 2) to chose between two instructions and I would like to use with an instruction which have a comma.

```
#define option 1

#if option == 1
#define my_instr(instr1, instr2) instr1
#else if option == 2
#define my_instr(instr1, instr2) instr2
#endif
```

It works but when there is a comma in the instruction, I have a problem.

For example :

```
program main

 my_instr(print *,"opt 1", print * ,"opt 2")

end program main
```

does not compile (gftran -cpp) : Too much args. I am ok.

Thus, to escape the comma, parentheses are added  : `my_instr((print *,"opt 1"), (print * ,"opt 2"))`

But it does not compile any more because of parentheses.

How can I solve that ?

Comment: `I found a solution.` Post it as a solution and accept the answer. Yes, to preserve the comma you have to put it inside parens.

Comment: `it is not recommanded to use VA_ARGS` no no, `__VA_ARGS__` is standard. Using empty argument list `(...)` is technically not-standard. You have to `(something, ...)`. That said, I think all compilers will compile just fine.

Comment: @KamilCuk. Thanks for comments. I posted an answer and modified my remark on `__VA_ARGS__`.  Do not hesitate to edit it. It will be better than my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46311121/7462275), I found a " solution ".

```
#define option 2

#define unparen(...) __VA_ARGS__

#if option == 1
#define my_instr(instr1, instr2) unparen instr1
#elif option == 2
#define my_instr(instr1, instr2) unparen instr2
#endif

 program main
 
   my_instr((print *,"opt 1"), (print * ,"opt 2"))

 end program main
```

But,

1. `gfortran -cpp` does not compile (problem with `__VA_ARGS__`). So, `cpp -P` is used before `gfortran`
2. `__VA_ARGS__` : It is not standard to use `__VA_ARGS__` without `something` before (cf comments of :
   Matthew D. Scholefield in the answer used :
   *Just something to note, this still doesn't conform to the C standard because of the use of a variadic macro.* 
   and KamilCuk in this question)
3. Even instructions without comma need to be enclosed between parentheses

Comment: You don't need `unparen` and `invoke`, just `#define my_instr(instr1, instr2) really_unparen instr1`.

Answer (score 2):

This will select the correct string.

```
#ifdef my_instr
#undef my_instr
#endif
#define my_instr(x) print *, x

#if option == 1
#define str "Opt 1"
#else if option == 2
#define str "Opt 2"
#endif

program foo
  my_instr(str)
end program foo

% gfortran -E -Doption=2 a.F90 | cat -s
# 1 "a.F90"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "a.F90"

program foo
  print *, "Opt 2"
end program foo
```

Comment: I agree with you. But `print`  is only an example.  I am looking for a more generic macro.